# Does every docker compose yml file is compatible with AWS ECS containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have a docker-compose yml file. It contains 11 services/sections. I am able to successfully deploy it on Ubuntu EC2 instance.

Now, I need to host each service/ section from Docker Compose inside AWS ECS. As per my understanding, I need to create a task definition from AWS ECS UI. I can look at my docker-compose file for image details, environment variables, labels, and just add it inside the task definition. Then, start the task. Now, my ECS tasks should work without any additional settings.

Is this a correct understanding that any service/section docker-compose yml file is ECS compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, ECS still doesn't allow the build command in docker-compose.yml so you will run into some headaches. 
You can build separate images on ECR and have your docker-compose file to run those when you are creating your services. Don't forget to rebuild those images when you are deploying new code.

**Sample docker-compose file**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    image: some_repository/web:latest
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: some_other_repo/db:latest
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's more than I expected. My Query is very basic. I just want to understand compatibility. One of the projects has given its docker-compose file. It has 11 sections. Can I safely assume that even if I try manually, I can create task definitions and tasks in ECS just by looking at the docker-compose file? Section in docker compose indicates that I can host them in ECS containers..

Comment: @user660232 I recommend that you go through this https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-fargate.html It will help you understand things a bit better and also the ecs cli will make your life easier when dealing with ECS. Don't forget to go through the installation steps a few sections up.

Comment: @user660232 please remember to accept the answer or let us know if you are still in need of help.